# Ubuntu Stuck at purple screen

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10 and it booted a couple of times untill is stopped working I tried nomodeset but it was stuck at "Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded" Sometimes stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manger" Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Indicate version of Ubuntu you are using. 18.04 at one time had the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1779948 which should be fixed. So if using 18.04, make sure you fully update: using grub menu, boot to "recovery mode" then select "root terminal with networking" and run "sudo apt update ;  sudo apt upgrade", then reboot with "reboot". Workaround would be to fully remove "snap" but it is better to see whether update fixes it.

Comment: Now it's stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manger"

Comment: After applying the steps

Comment: So at least your system is up to date. Better add the Ubuntu version to your post (use "edit")

Comment: It's Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Editing Grub**
When you boot your system, just stop at the Grub screen like the one below. If you don’t see this screen, keep holding Shift key at the boot time.

At this screen, press ‘E’ key to go into the editing mode.
[image]

You should see some sort of code like the one below. You should focus on the line that starts with Linux.

[image]

**Step 2: Temporarily Modifying Linux kernel parameters in Grub**
Remember, our problem is with the NVIDIA Graphics drivers. This incompatibility with open source version of NVIDIA drivers caused the issue so what we can do here is to disable these drivers.

Now, there are several ways you can try to disable these drivers. My favorite way is to disable all video/graphics card using nomodeset.

Just add the following text at the end of the line starting with Linux. You should be able to type normally. Just make sure that you are adding it at the end of the line.
Now it will look like this.
[image]
**Step 3: Make permanent changes in Grub**

Don’t be too happy yet just because you are able to login to your system now. What you did was temporary and the next time you boot into your system, your system will still freeze because it will still try to load the graphics drivers.

Does this mean you’ll always have to edit Kernel from the grub screen? Thankfully, the answer is no.

What you can do here to change the grub configuration so that the Linux kernel will not try to load the graphics driver before the display server.

To do that, open the terminal (use Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut) and then use the following command to open the grub configuration file in Gedit editor:
    sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

You’ll have to use your password to open this file. Once you have the text file opened, look for the line that contains: 
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash".

Change this line to: 
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

It should look something like this:
[image]

Save the file and update grub so that changes are taken into effect. Use this command:
    sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "nomodeset" didn't work so it actually was something very wierd 
I went into recovery mode 
And selected "Contionue normal boot" 
then I Pressed (Ctrl + Alt + F2) 
and did NOT log in but pressed (Ctrl + Alt +F1) 
and Ubuntu booted normally